# How to generate primes of the form 8n+1?

Tags: list-manipulation, prime-numbers

I'm trying to extract from the list of the first one hundred primes those which have the form 8n+1. 
I have tried using Select but this just gives me an empty list:

```
Select[Table[Prime[n], {n, 1, 100}] , Mod[n, 8] == 1]
```

I have also tried using Array but this crashes every time:

```
Select[Array[Prime, Prime[Range[100]]], Mod[#, 8] == 1 &]
```

The following code works but this is not quite what I'm looking for:

```
Select[Array[Prime, PrimePi[100]], Mod[#, 8] == 1 &]
```

Comment: `Select[Table[Prime[n], {n, 1, 100}], Mod[#, 8] == 1 &]` I'm not sure but maby this

Comment: `Pick[#, Mod[#, 8], 1] &@Prime@Range@100`

Comment: you can also reverse the process as : `Select[8 Range[100] + 1, PrimeQ]`

Answer (score 8):

I'll comment on why your initial attempts failed and attempt to correct them.  Others have done a better job suggesting better approaches.

```
(* Fails -- second argument of Select needs to be a function *)
Select[Table[Prime[n], {n, 1, 100}] , Mod[n, 8] == 1]
```

In the first argument, you generated a list of the first 100 primes (as desired).  But the second argument of `Select` needs to be a function.  As David Baghdasaryan noted in the comments and David G Stork cleaned abbreviated in his answer, simply making the second argument a pure function works:

```
(* Works -- as suggested by David G Stork *)
Select[Prime[Range[100]], Mod[#,8] == 1&]
```

---

```
(* Fails -- list of primes constructed improperly *)
Select[Array[Prime, Prime[Range[100]]], Mod[#, 8] == 1 &]
```

This correctly passes a function in the second argument, but the list of primes is constructed improperly.  Actually, if you replaced `Array` with `Table`, this would have worked, but `Array` has different syntax.  The second argument of `Array` always specifies the length of the list.  You passed a list of the first 100 primes, so `Array` attempted to construct a list with 100 nestings.

Actually, it would be fairly terse to write

```
(* Works *)
Select[Array[Prime, 100], Mod[#, 8] == 1 &]
```

which works similarly to David G Stork's method with marginally fewer characters.

---

```
(* Partially succeeds-- list of primes only partially constructed *)
Select[Array[Prime, PrimePi[100]], Mod[#, 8] == 1 &]
```

`PrimePi[100]` returns the number of primes less than, which is 25, so this method is equivalent to writing `Select[Array[Prime, 25], Mod[#, 8] == 1 &]`.  As you noted, this is not what you want.

Answer (score 5):

Inefficient, but works:

```
Intersection[
 Table[8 n + 1, {n, Round[Prime[100]/8]}], Prime[Range[100]] 
 ]
```

and a shorter implementation of David Baghdasaryan's solution:

```
Select[Prime@Range@100, Mod[#,8] == 1&]
```

Answer (score 4):

I prefer [@jjc385's explanatory answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/145816/142), but here are some ways to consider:

```
Prime[Range[100]] // Pick[#, Mod[#, 8], 1] &

Cases[Prime[Range[100]], p_ /; Mod[p, 8] == 1]

Select[Prime[Range[100]], Mod[#, 8] == 1 &]

Solve[p <= Prime[100] && Mod[p, 8] == 1, p, Primes]

Solve[p <= Prime[100] && p == 8 n + 1 && p ∈ Primes && n ∈ Integers, {p, n}]
```